# Question about paint clone projection

Tags: texture-painting

Is possible to paint clone a 360 photo environment?

I have it mapped as environment (jpeg) but i wish to match some geo to it. But i would like to paint some areas of interest.

Any idea how to set up this? Please.

its similar to this but i already have it modeled:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSC40B8kHT8

Comment: I might suggest looking at baking to a UV mapped image texture after you have completed the modeling as in the video, that way you are no longer bound to the 360 environment texture. The bake should then give you all of the projection into an image that you can then texture paint.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply and for your time Craig! I really apreciate! My english is not thaat good, i will try explain more: I already have the mesh. i modeled based on the 360 photo. I could get this 360 image and ~decompose~ it in small parts. But i would have to undistort and will lost a bit the sense of space in my scene. So i would project some parts while i can view and rotate. is that possible?

Comment: IF you bake the 360 image to the mesh on a new blank image mapped to the mesh UV, it should still give you the same feel as long as you use enough pixels in your bake image. I would still suggest keeping the 360 image as environment texture.

Comment: Still didnt find a way man. My english is not good, but what i wanted to make is what is guy was trying to:.

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/camera-mapping-and-spherical-projection/589085/5